# CURL post data not the same as form submit

Tags: php, apache, curl

I use `php` `cURL` to simulate posting data to server, but it not work the same as form submit.

`HTML` form code (it works):

```
form action="username:password@server.dev/abc" method="POST">
<input name='id' value='v1'>
<input name='body:query' value='v2'>
<input name='update' value='0'>
<input name='body:par1' value='xx'>
<input type='submit' value='GO'>
</form>
```

`CURL` code (not work):

```
$data = array('id'=>'v1', 'body:query'=>'v2', 'update'=>'0', 'body:par1'=>'xx');
$header = array(
            'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0',
            'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5',
            'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate',
            'Cookie: wait=1',
            'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode("{$strUser}:{$strPass}"),
            'Connection: keep-alive',
            "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $strUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$htmlDoc = curl_exec($ch);
```

"Not work" means the server return difference response.

One more thing is, when I submit the form above by `Firefox Developer Edition`, I open Network tab, click `Edit and Resend`, not edit any information, click `Send`. It not work too, the result as same as the result of `cURL` code.

As I know, server is `IBM_HTTP_SERVER/1.3.19.1  Apache/1.3.20 (Unix)`

I don't have any ideal how it happens. Please teach me!

Comment: Could be any number of reasons, but probably a CSRF token. Look in network tab and check the data that is sent by the form, my guess is there is more than the 4 fields you list above

Comment: What is the response you want, and what you did you get?

Comment: Thank you, @Steve, yes, the form have 106 fields. But I think the cause is token, because I simple get all in put of curl, make a simple html form in localhost with them, open the page in localhost, click submit. It works!

Comment: @frz3993, if it success, a table data will be returned. But in my case, the error message and error code returned. I don't know why, which the same data input, the server responses difference result.

Comment: Ok, so to clarify, you are saying that if you manually create an html form on your local computer, and submit it from a browser, it works?

Comment: You are correct, @Steve.

Answer (score 0):

First, correct the missing single quote from the value `v1`. After that use `http_build_query` on the `$data` array before sending as POST.

```
$data = array('id'=>'v1', 'body:query'=>'v2', 'update'=>'0', 'body:par1'=>'xx');
$data = http_build_query($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try json_encode for arrays:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
```